# Attempting to write image bytes from socket connection, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null

Tags: java, json, image, sockets

I'm trying to develop a custom low overhead image pipeline for processing images using direct socket connections.

I'm unable to recreate the images on the server side, however, the images cant be opened.

I have a client that takes screenshots from my screen & sends those screenshots via a socket connection.

**The data format being sent is   ds= data size , indicating JSON header size, then 8 chars (16 bytes for actual header size in bytes), then  JSON data that acts as header data which has file/application data, and immediately afterward are image bytes.**

**(Some backgroud, no need to read:)** I did not include the image bytes in the actual JSON body, because that required converting the image bytes to base64 which was very inefficient and caused messages about 25 secs to get across to the server.

**For example:**

```
ds222     {

"abcd_id":"1234567890",

"image_file_format":"png",

"image_encoding":"RGB_565",

"width_in_pixels":1024,

"height_in_pixels":2048,

"timestamp":"2019-01-31T20:48:59+00:00",

"data_array_size_in_bytes":"208670"
}
```

**Here is the client test program, that takes snapshot and sends over data:**

```
package SocketImageClient;


public class ImageClient {



    private static final SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSdataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    private static final String[] HEADER_FOR_INCOMING_DATA_INFO = {"d", "s", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "};
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String ipAddress = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 10002;

        int counter = 0;
          Robot r = null;
          int width=0; 
          int height=0; 
          String mime= "jpg";
          byte[] imageInByte = null; 

                while (counter < 5)
                {

            try {
                r = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ImageClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


            // Used to get ScreenSize and capture image 
            Rectangle capture =  new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()); 
            BufferedImage Image = r.createScreenCapture(capture); 
            try { 
                width = Image.getWidth();
                height = Image.getHeight(); 
                //get the bytes of the buffered image 
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( Image, "jpg", baos );
    baos.flush();
    imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ImageClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        sendImageDataTcp(ipAddress,port,"jpg",mime, width,height, yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSdataFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis()) ,imageInByte);
        counter++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ImageClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            counter++;
                }

    }


    private static void sendImageDataTcp(String ipAddress, int port, String fileFormat, String MIME, int widthPixels, int heightPixels, String timeStamp, byte[] imageBytes) {

        //String ipAddress = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        Socket socket = null;
        OutputStream os = null;

        try {


            socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);

            if (socket != null) {
                os = socket.getOutputStream();
                //make sure byte-enconding is UTF8 for actual JSON structure
                //OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                //test JSON
                String headerJson = "{\n"
                        + "  \"abcd_id\":\"1234567890\",\n"
                        + "  \"file_format\":\"jpg\",\n"
                        + "  \"image_compression\":\"RGB_565\",\n"
                        + "  \"width_in_pixels\":1024,\n"
                        + "  \"height_in_pixels\":2048,\n"
                        + "  \"timestamp\":\"2019-01-31T20:48:59+00:00\",\n"
                        + "  \"data_array_size_in_bytes\":\""+imageBytes.length+"\"\n"
                        + "}";

                //empty header
                String[] header_for_incoming_data_info = HEADER_FOR_INCOMING_DATA_INFO;
                //note we wan to length of  the bytes not JSONObject  length.
                String headerStringPlusSize = "ds" + headerJson.toString().getBytes().length;
                //set header based on the string  headerStringPlusSize
                for (int i = 0; i < headerStringPlusSize.length(); i++) {
                    header_for_incoming_data_info[i] = String.valueOf(headerStringPlusSize.charAt(i));
                }
                //entire entireMessage = header + json data
                StringBuilder entireMessage = new StringBuilder();
                for (int c = 0; c < header_for_incoming_data_info.length; c++) {
                    entireMessage.append(header_for_incoming_data_info[c]);
                }
                entireMessage.append(headerJson.toString());

                //write JSON HEADER
                os.write(entireMessage.toString().getBytes());
                //write image bytes  
                os.write(imageBytes);




            } else {
                //Log.e(TAG, "The the image transfer server cannot be reached!");
                System.out.println("The the image transfer server cannot be reached!");
            }

        } catch (java.net.ConnectException exc) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "The the image transfer server cannot be reached!");
            System.out.println("The the image transfer server cannot be reached!");
            exc.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "ex:" + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("ex:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } /*catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/ finally {
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //Log.e(TAG, "ex:" + ex.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("ex:" + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }//end client


}
```

**Here is the socket server that receives the bytes & attempts to recreate the image:**

```
package socketserver;



public class SocketServer {

    /**
     * How to run the program via if you have .class & via command line java -cp
     * ./classes socketserver.SocketServer 10001
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        System.out.println("1)Run the program from command prompt OR shell like by issuing this command.java -jar SocketServerGradle.jar <PORT_NUMBER>");
        System.out.println("Note: <PORT_NUMBER> must replace by actual port number. Like java -jar SocketServerGradle.jar 10001");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("2)Any other message format, will result in errors.");

        if (args[0] != null && args[0].length() > 0) {
            //a port number must be numeric 
            int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);

            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("***abcd to adrian image server started****");

                new Thread(new ServiceHandler(serverSocket)).start();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }//end args input validation 
        else {
        System.out.println("1)Run the program from command prompt OR shell like by issuing this command.java -jar SocketServerGradle.jar <PORT_NUMBER>");
        System.out.println("Note: <PORT_NUMBER> must replace by actual port number. Like java -jar SocketServerGradle.jar 10001");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("2)Any other message format, will result in errors.");

        }

    }//end main 

    private static class ServiceHandler implements Runnable {

        private ServerSocket serverSocket;

        public ServiceHandler(ServerSocket _serverSocket) {
            serverSocket = _serverSocket;
        }

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            BufferedReader bf = null;
            //stream suitable for reading raw bytes
            InputStream inputStream; 
            //stream suitable for reading characters
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader; 
            while (true) {

                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                } catch (java.net.BindException exc) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exc);
                    if (exc.getMessage().contains("Address") && exc.getMessage().contains("already") && exc.getMessage().contains("use")) {
                        System.out.println("Port already being used, make sure to kill previous instance of program.");
                        errorLog(exc.getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    errorLog(ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {

                    if (socket != null) {
                        inputStream = socket.getInputStream(); 
                        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                        int read = 0;
                        int counter = 0;
                        long size = 0;
                        //read the 1st 10 character (20 bytes) to get the header 
                        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((read = inputStreamReader.read()) != -1 && counter < 11) {
                            header.append((char) read);
                            counter++;
                        }
                        //ok inputStream the header valid, if the 1st two characters are ds then yes. 
                        if (header.length() > 1 && header.substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("ds")) {
                            System.out.println("Valid Header");

                            //now lets get the message size, which comes after the 2nd char until the 12th char. RThe size will be parsed into Long numeric value. 
                            try {
                                String sizedata = header.substring(2, 11).trim();
                                size = Long.valueOf(sizedata);
                                System.out.println("HEADER size in bytes:" + size);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
                                exc.printStackTrace();
                                errorLog(exc.getMessage());
                            }
                            //now that we have  the message size lets get the entire header which inputStream in JSON 
                            StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();

                            long byteCounter = 0;
                            while ((read = inputStreamReader.read()) != -1 && byteCounter < size) {
                                message.append((char) read);
                                byteCounter++;
                            }

                            ImagePayload imagePayload = parseJson(message.toString());

                            if (imagePayload != null) {
                                String logMsg = "parsed JSON & created:" + imagePayload;
                                System.out.println(logMsg);
                                logInfo(logMsg);

                                //after the JSON , get teh actual size of the image bytes that are sent after  the JSON header 
                                int actualImageBytesSize = imagePayload.getDataArraySizeInBytes();
                                System.out.println("Image size in bytes:" + actualImageBytesSize);
                                //get the image bytes
                                int imageBytesCounter = 0;

                                ByteArrayOutputStream byteos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int currentBytesRead=0; 
                                int totalBytesRead=0; 
                                while ((currentBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    byteos.write(buffer,0,currentBytesRead);
                                    totalBytesRead= totalBytesRead+ currentBytesRead; 
                                }
                                //log info 
                                String info = "total bytes Read:"+totalBytesRead+"expected number of bytes:"+actualImageBytesSize; 
                                System.out.println(info);
                                logInfo(info); 
                                //get the byte array and write the image to disk 
                                byteos.flush();
                                byte[] imageData = byteos.toByteArray();

                                BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData));

                                try
                                {
                                 //write
                                File imageFile = new File("." + File.separator + imagePayload.getabcdId()+"."+imagePayload.getImageFileFormat());
                //ERROR IS HERE -> attempt #1 
                               if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                                        imageFile.createNewFile();
                                    }
                                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,imagePayload.getImageFileFormat(), imageFile );

                                 //ERROR IS HERE attempt # 2 - although the file is written its it cant be opened. Windows creates JPG file but cant open it.  
                                /*FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                                fos.write(imageData);
                                fos.close();*/

                                }
                               catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exc)
                                {
                                     exc.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                catch (IOException exc)
                                {
                                    exc.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            } else {
                                String logErr = "Unable! to parse JSON::" + message.toString();
                                System.out.println(logErr);
                                logInfo(logErr);
                            }

                        } else {
                            System.err.println("invalid header!");
                            logInfo("invalid header!");
                        }

                    }

                } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                    errorLog(exc.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    errorLog(ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }//end while 
        }
    }

    private static ImagePayload parseJson(String message) {
        ImagePayload imagePayload = null;
        try {
            //parse JSON

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
            com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(message.toString());
            //Jackson JSON Tree Model
            JsonNode jacksonNode = mapper.readTree(parser);
            if (jacksonNode != null) {
                JsonNode abcdIdNode = jacksonNode.get("abcd_id");
                JsonNode imageFileFormatNode = jacksonNode.get("file_format");
                JsonNode imageEncodingNode = jacksonNode.get("image_compression");
                JsonNode imageWidthInPixelsNode = jacksonNode.get("width_in_pixels");
                JsonNode imageHeightInPixelsNode = jacksonNode.get("height_in_pixels");
                JsonNode dataArraySizeInBytesNode = jacksonNode.get("data_array_size_in_bytes");
                JsonNode timestampNode = jacksonNode.get("timestamp");

                String abcdId = abcdIdNode.textValue();
                String imageFileFormat = imageFileFormatNode.textValue();
                String imageCompression= imageEncodingNode.textValue();
                int width = imageWidthInPixelsNode.intValue();
                int height = imageHeightInPixelsNode.intValue();
                int dataArraySizeInBytes = dataArraySizeInBytesNode.asInt();
                String timestamp = timestampNode.asText();

                imagePayload = new ImagePayload(abcdId, imageFileFormat, imageCompression, width, height, dataArraySizeInBytes, timestamp);

            } else {
                String errorMsg = "Error parsing json, JsonNode=" + jacksonNode + ", message:" + message;
                System.err.println(errorMsg);
                errorLog(errorMsg);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            String err  = "ImagePayload parseJson(), message:"+message+",exc:"+ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(err);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            errorLog(err);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException exc)
        {
            String err  = "ImagePayload parseJson(), message:"+message+",exc:"+exc.getMessage();
            System.out.println(err);
            exc.printStackTrace();
            errorLog(err);
        }

        return imagePayload;
    }

    private static void logInfo(String message) {
        try {
            File logFile = new File("." + File.separator + "abcd_adrian_IMG_INFO_LOG.log");
            if (!logFile.exists()) {
                logFile.createNewFile();
            }
            message = "\n" + message;
            Files.write(Paths.get(logFile.getAbsolutePath()), message.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    private static void errorLog(String message) {
        try {
            File logFile = new File("." + File.separator + "abcd_adrian_IMG_ERROR_LOG.log");
            if (!logFile.exists()) {
                logFile.createNewFile();
            }
            message = "\n" + message;
            Files.write(Paths.get(logFile.getAbsolutePath()), message.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

**Attempt #1 CMD Output (relevant snippets):**

***abcd to adrian image server started****
Valid Header

HEADER size in bytes:219

**parsed JSON & created:ImagePayload{abcdId=1234567890, ImageFileFormat=jpg, ImageEncoding=RGB_565, WidthInPixels=1024, HeightInPixels=2048, DataArraySizeInBytes=132561, Timestamp=2019-01-31T20:48:59+00:00}**

Image size in bytes:132561
**total bytes Read:124369expected number of bytes:132561**

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**: image == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1592)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
    at socketserver.SocketServer$ServiceHandler.run(SocketServer.java:216)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I played around with hardcoding the format to JPEG,jpeg,PNG,png,etc... however  I got the same IllegalArgumentException was being thrown.

**I also noticed as you can see in the logs, that the socket might have not read the entire bytes?**

**total bytes Read:124369expected number of bytes:132561**

**Attempt #2 CMD Output (relevant snippets):**

***abcd to adrian image server started****

Valid Header
HEADER size in bytes:219
parsed JSON & created:ImagePayload{abcdId=1234567890, ImageFileFormat=jpg, ImageEncoding=RGB_565, WidthInPixels=1024, HeightInPixels=2048, DataArraySizeInBytes=129122, Timestamp=2019-01-31T20:48:59+00:00}
Image size in bytes:129122

total bytes Read:121161expected number of bytes:129122

**For attempt #2, Instead of using:**

```
 ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,imagePayload.getImageFileFormat(), imageFile );
```

**I used:**

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                                fos.write(imageData);
                                fos.close();
```

At this point I was able to write a file to the drive, **however I could not open it.** When I click on the file Windows OS, says "it looks like we dont support this file format". Although the file is recognized as JPG on the filesystem.

Any thoughts on why the entire bytes are not being read OR how I can fix this code in order to send both my JSON header and image bytes in one shot?

**UPADTE, BASED COMMENTS:**

I included the updated snippet for the client due to Stackoverflow limit, basically  the cliet is written JSON+image [] bytes

```
    new DataOutputStream(os).writeUTF(headerJson);
    //write image bytes  
    os.write(imageBytes);
```

Relevant server  snippt:

```
  if (socket != null) {
                        inputStream = socket.getInputStream(); 
                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                        String message = dis.readUTF();
                         //now that we have  the message size lets get the entire header which inputStream in JSON 


                            ImagePayload imagePayload = parseJson(message);

                            if (imagePayload != null) {
                                String logMsg = "parsed JSON & created:" + imagePayload;
                                System.out.println(logMsg);
                                logInfo(logMsg);

                                //after the JSON , get teh actual size of the image bytes that are sent after  the JSON header 
                                int actualImageBytesSize = imagePayload.getDataArraySizeInBytes();
                                //get the image bytes
                                int imageBytesCounter = 0;

                                ByteArrayOutputStream byteos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int currentBytesRead=0; 
                                int totalBytesRead=0; 
                                while ((currentBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    byteos.write(buffer,0,currentBytesRead);
                                    totalBytesRead= totalBytesRead+ currentBytesRead; 
                                }
                                //log info 
                                String info = "total bytes Read:"+totalBytesRead+",expected number of bytes:"+actualImageBytesSize; 
                                System.out.println(info);
                                logInfo(info); 
                                //get the byte array and write the image to disk 
                                byteos.flush();
                                byte[] imageData = byteos.toByteArray();

                                BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData));

                                try
                                {
                                 //write
                                File imageFile = new File("." + File.separator + imagePayload.getWamsId()+"."+imagePayload.getImageFileFormat());
                               if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                                        imageFile.createNewFile();
                                    }
                                //Attempt #1 
                                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"jpeg", imageFile );

                                 //attempt # 2 - although the file is written its it cant be opened 
                                /*FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                                fos.write(imageData);
                                fos.close();*/

                                }
                               catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exc)
                                {
                                     exc.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                catch (IOException exc)
                                {
                                    exc.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            } else {
                                String logErr = "Unable! to parse JSON::" + message.toString();
                                System.out.println(logErr);
                                logInfo(logErr);
                            }

                    }
```

The program now works perfectly but on Windows only. When  I move server code to linux Amazon AWS, the server runs gets the JSON correctly & creates the image but the image cant be opened again?? Why can the image(JPG) only be open when the server is running on Windows?

**I get this exception on linux only:**

```
total bytes Read:15805440,expected number of bytes:15805440
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
        at socketserver.SocketServer$ServiceHandler.run(SocketServer.java:186)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
total bytes Read:15805440,expected number of bytes:15805440
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't see any glaring errors, so I suggest you narrow this down a bit, like writing the file to disk on the client and checking that it is OK, or try sending just the image data (get rid of json)

Comment: Clearly the image wasn't transmitted correctly, so `ImageIO.readImage()` returned null, which you failed to check for. But you are wasting time and space. You could just do `ImageIO.read(inputStream)` and cut all the cackle with byte array input and output streams. I would also get rid of the 11 byte header and put it into `ImagePayload`. There are too many protocols here.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I wrote only image bytes without the JSON & it worked! However im not sure why. The  JSON was being deserialized correctly which means the server side was reading correct bytes & then reading  he image bytes. The issue was it was ending the read to early. I need to figure this out because I need to send other data such as user_id, timestamp, etc in  the same payload NOT just image bytes.

Comment: @user207421, without using HTTP(which has headers) or higher level protocols you need a header, the header here tells me were JSON starts and ends, and were my image bytes begin. Its just one protocol.

Comment: It's three protocols. (1) 11 bytes of first header, (2) `ImagePayload` encoded as JSON, and (3) the image itself, as bytes. It's too many. You can get rid of the first header, which is only the length of the second, JSON part; write the JSON data with `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()/writeInt()`, reading it with `DataInputStream.readUTF()/readInt()`, and then follow it immediately with the image via `ImageIO.write()` and `ImageIO.read()`, with no byte array streams or JSON at all.

Comment: @user207421, really appreciate I made the changes, however it only works on windows when i  move the server.jar to linux I get the same error. JSON and image are read but the image cant be opened on linux only on windows? When I move the image using FTP to windows i still cant be opened? The linux version says `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!` Odd "write once run everywhere :)